# How to fill a region given by an implicit function with gnuplot in tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf, gnuplot

I want to create a plot the region where `f(x,y) = -2 + 3x - y - x^2 - xy - y^2 > 0` in TikZ in the range `[-2.5, 2.5] \times [2.5, 2.5]`. Since this is an implicit function, I think I must use `gnuplot`, I currently can only plot `f(x,y) = 0`, I have tried using:

[Edit: Updated with minimal working example]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.38]
        \clip (-2.5,-2.5) rectangle (2.5,2.5);
        \draw plot[raw gnuplot, fill=blue!50] function{
        f(x,y) = -2 * 1 +  3 * x +  -1 * y +  -1 * x**2 +  -1 * x*y +  -1 * y**2;
        set view 0,0;
        set isosample 1000, 1000;
        set size square;
        set contour base;
        set cntrparam levels incre 0,0.1,0;
        unset surface;
        splot [-2.5:2.5] [-2.5:2.5] f(x,y);
        };
        \draw (-2.5,-2.5) rectangle (2.5,2.5);
    \end{tikzpicture}%
\end{document}
```

Which produce the following result:

[image]

I have also tried using the following function instead, but it gave me a "blocky" contour instead.

```
f(x, y) = (\coeff[#1,1] * 1 + \coeff[#1,2] * x + \coeff[#1,3] * y + \coeff[#1,4] * x**2 + \coeff[#1,5] * x*y + \coeff[#1,6] * y**2 > 0)?0:1;
```

Is there any way to colour the region where `f(x,y)>0`?

P.S. Since I have a lot of different quadratic to colour, I am looking for a solution which can colour `f(x,y)>0` where `f(x,y)` is a quadratic.

Comment: Welcome. What is your minimal working example, please? I see only a fragment.

Comment: @Sebastiano I have added the minimal working example in the question, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that gnu plot generates a number of short stretches rather than one continuous stretch. You can see this by looking at the .table file which gets generated. You can also see this by placing `fill=blue!50` where it belongs, namely `\draw[fill=blue] plot ...`. It may be possible to convince gnu plot to draw the contour in one stretch. However, it is also possible to solve the problem analytically. As is well known, the solutions of your implicit quadratic equation leads to conic sections. It is straightforward, though tedious, to implement the analytic solutions in a tikz `pic`. In this code, this is spelled out for the case of an ellipse, which is what you get for your choice of the coefficient. The other cases are analogous. In your use case you will then get

[image]

This is the code with defines the `pic` and produces this figure along with some discussion.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
\usepackage{xurl}
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{declare function={%
    conicdet2(\a,\b,\c)=-\b*\b/4+\a*\c;
    conicdet3(\a,\b,\c,\d,\e,\f)=(-\c*\d*\d+\b*\d*\e-\a*\e*\e-\b*\b*\f+4*\a*\c*\f)/4;},
    pics/conic section/.style n args={6}{code={%
        \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\mydiscriminant}{sign(-4*conicdet2(#1,#2,#3))+1}%
        \ifcase\mydiscriminant\relax 
            % ellipse
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\mya}{-sqrt(2*((#1)*(#5)*(#5)+(#3)*(#4)*(#4)-(#2)*(#4)*(#5)+((#2)*(#2)-4*(#1)*(#3))*(#6))*((#1)+(#3)+sqrt(((#1)-(#3))*((#1)-(#3))+(#2)*(#2))))/((#2)*(#2)-4*(#1)*(#3))}%
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\myb}{-sqrt(2*((#1)*(#5)*(#5)+(#3)*(#4)*(#4)-(#2)*(#4)*(#5)+((#2)*(#2)-4*(#1)*(#3))*(#6))*((#1)+(#3)-sqrt(((#1)-(#3))*((#1)-(#3))+(#2)*(#2))))/((#2)*(#2)-4*(#1)*(#3))}%
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\myx}{(2*(#3)*(#4)-(#2)*(#5))/((#2)*(#2)-4*(#1)*(#3))}%
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\myy}{(2*(#1)*(#5)-(#2)*(#4))/((#2)*(#2)-4*(#1)*(#3))}%
            \ifdim#2pt=0pt\relax 
                \ifdim#1pt<#3pt\relax 
                    \pgfmathsetmacro{\mytheta}{0}%
                \else 
                    \pgfmathsetmacro{\mytheta}{90}%
                \fi
            \else 
                \pgfmathsetmacro{\mytheta}{atan((#2)/((#3)-(#1)-sqrt(((#1)-(#3))*((#1)-(#3))+(#2)*(#2))))}% 
            \fi
            % debug
            %\typeout{A=#1,B=#2,C=#3,D=#4,E=#5,F=#6,a=\mya,b=\myb,x=\myx,y=\myy,theta=\mytheta}%
            \draw[pic actions,rotate around={\mytheta:(\myx,\myy)},shift={(\myx,\myy)}] circle[x radius=\mya,y radius=\myb]; 
        \or 
            % parabola
            % not implemented
        \or
            % hyperbola
            % not implemented
    \fi
    }}
}
\begin{document}
It is well known that the implicit equation 
\begin{equation}\label{eq:quadratic}
 A\,x^2+B\,x\,y+C\,y^2+D\,x+E\,y+F=0    
\end{equation}
leads to conic sections, see e.g.\ \url{https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conic_section}. Depending on the sign of $B^2-4AC$ one obtains an ellipse ($<0$), parabola ($=0$) or hyperbola ($>0$). The ellipse case is discussed in more detail at e.g.\ \url{https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipse#Canonical_form}, where explicit expressions for the axes, shift and rotations in terms of the coefficients of the quadratic equation \eqref{eq:quadratic} are given. This allows one to define a \texttt{pic} that draws the conic section in terms of the parameters. 
\begin{figure}[htb]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.38]
        \draw (-2.5,-2.5) rectangle (2.5,2.5);
        \clip (-2.5,-2.5) rectangle (2.5,2.5);
        \path pic[transform shape,fill=blue]{conic section={-1}{-1}{-1}{3}{-1}{-2}};  
        \draw plot[raw gnuplot] function{
        f(x,y) = -2 * 1 +  3 * x +  -1 * y +  -1 * x**2 +  -1 * x*y +  -1 * y**2;
        set view 0,0;
        set isosample 1000, 1000;
        set size square;
        set contour base;
        set cntrparam levels incre 0,0.1,0;
        unset surface;
        splot [-2.5:2.5] [-2.5:2.5] f(x,y);
        };
    \end{tikzpicture}%
    \caption{Elliptical conic section.}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```